# How is transaction right way?

Tags: codeigniter, transactions

I have a problem with transaction in code igniter. I wonder that how to use transaction to right way in this case :

```
foreach (items) {
   $this->db->trans_begin();

   addItemToArrayTotal_1();
   $items = getItem();
   if (items == null) {
      addItemToArrayTotal_2();
      if (!updateTask_1()) {
         addItemToArrayTotal_3();
      }
      continue;
   }
   if (updateTask_2()) {
      addItemToArrayTotal_4();
      if (!updateTask_3()) {
         addItemToArrayTotal_5();
      }
      if (updateTask_4()) {
         addItemToArrayTotal_6();
      }
   }
   addItemToArrayTotal_7();
}
```

- addItemToArrayTotal_?() are just integrating functions with array, not with data.
- updateTask_?() are interacting functions with data.

I want to process one by one items and will rollback in case be error occurred. Please suggest for me how to rollback data ?

Answer (score 1):

**The inherent nature of transactions is that they automatically rollback if one database query fails.**

Example:

```
$this->db->trans_start();
$this->db->insert(...);
$this->db->update(...);
$this->db->delete(...);
$this->db->trans_complete();
return $this->db->trans_status();
```

If the delete query fails, the update and insert query will be rolled back.

In CodeIgniter you don't need any logic to assure this*, simply use `trans_start()` before you start the query block you wish to be transactional and `trans_complete()` after.

*(unless you do transactions manually: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html#running-transactions-manually)

To assure this methodology, don't disable `trans_strict`. https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html#strict-mode

**TL;DR follow this example https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html#managing-errors and you'll be fine**